# When should I use `drain` vs `into_iter`?

Tags: iterator, rust

On the surface, it looks like both [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) and [`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_iter) provide similar iterators, namely over the values of the collection. However, they are different:

```
fn main() {
    let mut items1 = vec![0u8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    let items2 = items1.clone();

    println!("{:?}", items1.drain().count());
    println!("{:?}", items2.into_iter().count());

    println!("{:?}", items1);
    // println!("{:?}", items2); Moved
}
```

`drain` takes a `&mut` to the collection and the collection is available afterwards. `into_iter` consumes the collection. What are the appropriate uses for each iterator?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are somewhat redundant with each other. However, as you say, `Drain` just borrows the vector, in particular, it has a lifetime connected with the vector. If one is wishing to return an iterator, or otherwise munge iterators in the most flexible way possible, using `into_iter` is better, since it's not chained to the owner of the originating `Vec`. If one is wishing to reuse the data structure (e.g. reuse the allocation) then `drain` is the most direct way of doing this.

Also, a (somewhat) theoretical concern is that `Drain` *needs* to result in the originating structure being a valid instance of whatever type it is, that is, either preserve invariants, or fix them up at the end, while `IntoIter` can mangle the structure as much as it likes, since it has complete control of the value.

I say only "somewhat" theoretical because there is a small, real world example of this in `std` already: `HashMap` exposes `.drain` and `.into_iter` via its internal `RawTable` type, which also has those methods. `into_iter` can just [read the hash of the value being moved directly](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/099b411e080d302ec0dc5f3aebe53d76c50acfc7/src/libstd/collections/hash/table.rs#L898) and that's that, but `drain` has to be careful [to update the hash to indicate that the cell is then empty](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/099b411e080d302ec0dc5f3aebe53d76c50acfc7/src/libstd/collections/hash/table.rs#L898), not just read it. Obviously this is absolutely tiny in this instance (probably only one or two additional instructions) but for more complicated data structures like trees there may be some non-trivial gains to be had from breaking the invariants of the data structure.

Comment: It seems `.drain` for HashMap results in clearing the originating structure, and it can't work on a subset of the structure. So effectively what's the difference? `drain` doesn't take ownership but results in the original structure being cleared, and `.into_iter` takes ownership so the original structure can not be used and is left as an empty husk?

Comment: If the vector is in a struct, you can't simply convert the vec into an iterator it; you would need to either implement IntoIterator for the struct, or drain the vector.

Answer (score 21):

After using [`drain`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain), the `Vec` is empty but the storage previously allocated for its elements remains allocated. This means that you can insert new elements in the `Vec` without having to allocate storage for them until you reach the `Vec`'s [capacity](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#capacity-and-reallocation).

Note that before you can use the `Vec` again, you must drop all references to the [`Drain`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Drain.html) iterator. `Drain`'s implementation of `Drop` will remove all elements that hadn't been removed from the `Vec` yet, so the `Vec` will be empty even if you didn't finish the iteration.

Comment: Would you say that the *only* reason to use `.drain(..)` is to prseerve the memory allocation of the original structure: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58262920/124486

Answer (score 11):

For the 2018 edition of Rust:

`into_iter` consumes the collection itself, `drain` only consumes the values in the collection.

Therefore `drain` allows draining of only a part of the collection, and now in fact requires specifying a range. (This appears to have changed since when the question was asked.)

So use `into_iter` if you want to consume the entire collection, and use `drain` if you only want to consume part of the collection or if you want to reuse the emptied collection later.