# How to filter a vector of custom structs based on a string field

Tags: rust

First of all, note that I have seen [How to filter a vector of custom structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662312/how-to-filter-a-vector-of-custom-structs-in-rust) already, however, it doesn't contain the solution to my issue (or at least I can't see one). The main difference is that in my filter I try to use contain() method of a string. It is better if I show it with an example.

Here are my structs:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Spell {
    pub title: String,
    pub code: String,
    pub category: String,
    pub sub_category: String,
    pub tool: String,
    pub file_name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SearchParameters {
    pub category: String,
    pub sub_category: String,
    pub tool: String,
    pub search_str: String,
}
```

And here's the function I try to process the vector in:

```rust
pub fn search_spell(&self, search_parameters: SearchParameters) -> Vec<Spell> {
    let tmp_results: Vec<Spell> = self
        ._spell_list
        .clone()
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|spell| {
            if search_parameters.category.is_empty() {
                true
            } else {
                *spell.category == search_parameters.category
            }
        })
        .filter(|spell| {
            if search_parameters.sub_category.is_empty() {
                true
            } else {
                *spell.sub_category == search_parameters.sub_category
            }
        })
        .filter(|spell| {
            if search_parameters.tool.is_empty() {
                true
            } else {
                *spell.tool == search_parameters.tool
            }
        })
        .filter(|spell| {
            if search_parameters.search_str.is_empty() {
                true
            } else {
                //*spell.title.contains(search_parameters.search_str)
                true
            }
        })
        .collect();

    // TODO: replace this part by including in the filer above  
    let mut results: Vec<Spell> = Vec::new();
    for spell in tmp_results {
        if search_parameters.search_str.is_empty() {
            results.push(spell);
        } else {
            if spell
                .title
                .to_lowercase()
                .contains(&search_parameters.search_str.to_lowercase())
            {
                results.push(spell);
            }
        }
    }

    results
}
```

The issue is with the last filter block (see the commented code), where instead of `==` comparison, I would like to use `.contains()` method. The issue is that at the compile time, the compiler can't be sure what this value actually is.

For now, I have resolved this by processing the vector in the loop at the end of this method, but it feels a little bit forced if you know what I mean. I really think I should be able to resolve this somehow in the filter.

Comment: For the first chunk you probably want `self._spell_list.iter().filter(...).cloned().collect()` to avoid cloning the elements that don't get produced. You could also have the function itself return `impl Iterator<Item=&'_ Spell>` and have the caller decide if they need to clone the items, or if it's sufficient to borrow the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things to fix up here.  Let's go over them one by one.

The first is the issue you're having.  The problem is that `Pattern` is only implemented for `&str` but you're trying to give it `String`.  This is solved easily enough by borrowing the `String` as a slice -- just prefix the whole expression with `&` (which you do in your `for` loop).

However, invoking `to_lowercase()` in the `filter` closure is wasteful: the `search_str` value doesn't change, but you'll perform the conversion and allocation for each item in the original collection.  Instead, invoke `to_lowercase()` outside of the `filter` closure and move the result into the closure.

Finally, `contains()` returns a `bool` so the `*` is an error.  Dereferencing a `bool` makes no sense; just omit the `*` to return the `bool`.

Also, you clone the entire `Vec<Spell>` and then filter that, which is also wasteful.  You clone items that may never be produced.  Instead, consider this method chain, which only clones the items that are actually produced:

```
self._spell_list
    .iter()
    .filter(...)
    .filter(...)
    .cloned()
    .collect();
```

Even better, have the method return `impl Iterator<Item=&'_ Spell>` and avoid cloning altogether!  If the caller needs to clone the items, they can, otherwise they can use the borrowed `Spell`s without needing to clone.

To make returning an iterator of references work, we need to destructure the `SearchParameters` and move each element into the respective closure, or combine the various `filter`s into one single `filter`, or we need to borrow `SearchParameters` from the caller instead of taking it by value, but borrowing it is a good change as well: the caller can reuse `SearchParameters` values multiple times, since this function doesn't need to take ownership of it.

Finally, we can make the logic of each `filter` more terse by applying the transformation: `if x { true } else { y }` becomes `x || y`.

Putting all these changes together:

```
pub fn search_spell<'a>(&'a self, search_parameters: &'a SearchParameters)
    -> impl Iterator<Item=&'a Spell>
{
    let search_str = search_parameters.search_str.to_lowercase();
    
    self
        ._spell_list
        .iter()
        .filter(|spell| {
            search_parameters.category.is_empty() ||
            *spell.category == search_parameters.category
        })
        .filter(|spell| {
            search_parameters.sub_category.is_empty() ||
            *spell.sub_category == search_parameters.sub_category
        })
        .filter(|spell| {
            search_parameters.tool.is_empty() ||
            *spell.tool == search_parameters.tool
        })
        .filter(move |spell| {
            search_str.is_empty() ||
            spell.title.contains(&search_str)
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I realize that I haven't written my code like a true Rustacean. However, for the purpose of understanding the actual issue, it seems that the only missing thing (just to make it work) was the ``move`` in the last filter. Anyway, thanks for a very in-depth answer, very informative.

Comment: @0x4ndy Not quite -- `move` is needed to make the "don't call `to_lowercase()` every iteration" optimization work in combination with the "return an `Iterator`" change. (Since `search_str` is owned by the outer function, we need to move it into the closure to keep it alive.) All you actually need to change in your code for it to compile is to remove the `*` and add a `&` before `search_parameters.search_str.to_lowercase()`.